# Generic Vector implemented in C language

Tags: algorithm, c, stl

I am on the way implementing my own STL-like library in C language. The main reasons are learning DS&A better, as well as the C language itself. Here I am trying to implement Vector (a.k.a. array-list) data structure. Would really appreciate to hear constructive criticism. Please, kindly give your thoughts on how the code can be further improved performance, readability, and maintenance wise.

File: ue_vector.h

```
#ifndef UE_VECTOR_H
#define UE_VECTOR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct ue_vector {
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t data_size;
    void** data;
} ue_vector;

ue_vector*  ue_vector_start         (size_t init_capacity, size_t data_size);
void        ue_vector_finish        (ue_vector* vect);

size_t      ue_vector_length        (const ue_vector* const vect);
size_t      ue_vector_capacity      (const ue_vector* const vect);
size_t      ue_vector_data_size     (const ue_vector* const vect);
bool        ue_vector_is_empty      (const ue_vector* const vect);

void        ue_vector_resize        (ue_vector* vect);
void        ue_vector_shrink_to_fit (ue_vector* vect);

void        ue_vector_add_back      (ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added);
void        ue_vector_add_front     (ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added);
void        ue_vector_add_in        (ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added, size_t pos);

void*       ue_vector_get_back      (const ue_vector* const vect);
void*       ue_vector_get_front     (const ue_vector* const vect);
void*       ue_vector_get_in        (const ue_vector* const vect, size_t pos);

void        ue_vector_delete_back   (ue_vector* vect);
void        ue_vector_delete_front  (ue_vector* vect);
void        ue_vector_delete_in     (ue_vector* vect, size_t pos);

#endif // UE_VECTOR_H
```

File: ue_vector.c

````
#include "ue_vector.h"

ue_vector* ue_vector_start(size_t init_capacity, size_t data_size) {
    if (init_capacity == 0)
        init_capacity = 4;

    ue_vector* new_vect = (ue_vector*)malloc(sizeof(ue_vector));
    assert(new_vect != NULL);

    new_vect->data = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * init_capacity);
    assert(new_vect->data != NULL);

    new_vect->data_size = data_size;
    new_vect->capacity = init_capacity;
    new_vect->length = 0;

    return new_vect;
}

void ue_vector_finish(ue_vector* vect) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ue_vector_length(vect); ++i)
        free(vect->data[i]);
    free(vect->data);
    free(vect);
}

size_t ue_vector_length(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    return vect->length;
}

size_t ue_vector_capacity(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    return vect->capacity;
}

size_t ue_vector_data_size(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    return vect->data_size;
}

bool ue_vector_is_empty(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    return ue_vector_length(vect) == 0;
}

void ue_vector_resize(ue_vector* vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    if (ue_vector_length(vect) == ue_vector_capacity(vect)) {
        vect->capacity += ue_vector_capacity(vect) / 2;
        vect->data = (void**)realloc(vect->data, sizeof(void*) * ue_vector_capacity(vect));
    }
}

void ue_vector_shrink_to_fit(ue_vector* vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(!ue_vector_is_empty(vect));
    vect->capacity = ue_vector_length(vect) + 1;
    vect->data = (void**)realloc(vect->data, sizeof(void*) * ue_vector_capacity(vect));
}

void ue_vector_add_back(ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(to_be_added != NULL);
    if (!ue_vector_is_empty(vect))
        ue_vector_add_in(vect, to_be_added, ue_vector_length(vect));
    else
        ue_vector_add_in(vect, to_be_added, 0);
}

void ue_vector_add_front(ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(to_be_added != NULL);
    ue_vector_add_in(vect, to_be_added, 0);
}

void ue_vector_add_in(ue_vector* vect, const void* const to_be_added, size_t pos) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(to_be_added != NULL);
    assert(pos <= ue_vector_length(vect));

    ue_vector_resize(vect);
    vect->data[ue_vector_length(vect)] = (void*)malloc(ue_vector_data_size(vect));

    // moving elements
    for (size_t i = ue_vector_length(vect); i > pos; --i) {
        memcpy(vect->data[i], vect->data[i - 1], ue_vector_data_size(vect));
    }

    memcpy(vect->data[pos], to_be_added, ue_vector_data_size(vect));
    ++(vect->length);
}

void* ue_vector_get_back(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(ue_vector_length(vect) != 0);
    return ue_vector_get_in(vect, ue_vector_length(vect) - 1);
}

void* ue_vector_get_front(const ue_vector* const vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(ue_vector_length(vect) != 0);
    return ue_vector_get_in(vect, 0);
}

void* ue_vector_get_in(const ue_vector* const vect, size_t pos) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(ue_vector_length(vect) != 0);
    assert(pos < ue_vector_length(vect));
    return vect->data[pos];
}

void ue_vector_delete_back(ue_vector* vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(!ue_vector_is_empty(vect));
    ue_vector_delete_in(vect, ue_vector_length(vect) - 1);
}

void ue_vector_delete_front(ue_vector* vect) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(!ue_vector_is_empty(vect));
    ue_vector_delete_in(vect, 0);
}

void ue_vector_delete_in(ue_vector* vect, size_t pos) {
    assert(vect != NULL);
    assert(!ue_vector_is_empty(vect));
    assert(pos < ue_vector_length(vect));
    
    // moving elements
    for (size_t i = pos; i < ue_vector_length(vect) - 1; ++i) {
        memcpy(vect->data[i], vect->data[i + 1], ue_vector_data_size(vect));
    }

    free(vect->data[ue_vector_length(vect) - 1]);
    --(vect->length);
}
```
````

Comment: using `assert()` for validation is dangerous. In production `assert()` is a no-op and thus has no protective value. If any operations fails that was protected by an assert it now results in broken code that at best results in a crash at worst keeps on running have just corrupted some other piece of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design:

- Overall, function naming and const correctness etc looks good. The header is nicely formatted and easy to read. Most function names are self-explanatory, though I wouldn't use `start` and `finish`.

  Commonly used names for the constructor are `init`, `create`, `construct`, `alloc` etc.
  Commonly used names for the destructor is `delete`, `destruct`, `free`, `cleanup` etc.
- I'm getting some déjà vu from this whole vector implementation - check out [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249508/type-independent-vector-in-c/249612#249612) regarding how you could implement the concept of opaque type.
- It's strange and needlessly complicated to use `void**` for the data. Why can't you use `void*`, since all data stored can be assumed to be of the same type?
- `void*` is overall not very meaningful when dealing with raw data, so you should consider swapping it for `uint8_t*`.
- You should implement some manner of error handling through a return type `enum` or similar, rather than using `assert`.
- Generally, when developing actual library quality data containers, you should avoid excessive calls to malloc & realloc. These are very slow functions and calling them often also causes heap fragmentation and poor cache use etc. It is therefore custom to allocate a "x times alignment" capacity per vector instance, regardless of how much memory the user actually needs. There's plenty of heap memory, execution speed is much more important than a few bytes of RAM here and there.

  Example: Lets say you have a 32 bit CPU = 4 byte word alignment. The user wants to store 10 bytes of data. Regardless of that, you allocate a minimum of 4 * 8 = 32 bytes and keep track of how much of that memory that's used. 4 = alignment and 8 = some conventient multiple of 8. Then when the user requests a resize to 20 bytes, you simply mark 20 out of your 32 allocated bytes as used. Only when they go beyond the allocated size do you call malloc. But this time you allocate a total of 4 * 8*2 = 64 bytes. Next time 128 bytes, and so on. This is to reduce the amount of calls to malloc functions. And there is usually no need to shrink the allocated space, ever.

  The above is especially important for "`vector::push_back`"-like APIs, where you add one item at a time! You can't call malloc each time that happens, or you would have been better off using a linked list.
- With the above in mind, capacity should be handled internally by your code, not by the user! `capacity` should be a private variable and the caller shouldn't meddle with it.

Bugs:

- You don't check if `realloc` succeeded.

Style:

- It's a bit subjective, but in my opinion `const * const` function parameters are just clutter and should be changed to `const*`. The parameter is a *local copy* of the original pointer and the caller really couldn't care less if the function modifies that pointer internally. What meaningful change could a function do to a copy of a `void*` anyway?
- `--(vect->length);` looks strange, just write `vect->length--;`.
- Casting the result of malloc/realloc is pretty pointless and just adds clutter. In particularly, casting from `void*` to `void*` is very pointless.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am actually on the way of implementing my own enum error type.

Answer (score 3):

**Unneeded exposure**

The details of `ue_vector` are not needed in the *.h file.  `typedef struct ue_vector ue_vector;` is sufficient and promotes good information hiding.

Save the complete definition for the *.c file.

**Excess #include**

In the .h file only, `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdbool.h>` needed.

For .h files, good to keep *includes* to a minimum to reduce public name collisions and improve compile time.

Those other includes should be added to the *.c file.

**Consider `apply()`**

A candidate function to add would be

```
int ue_vector_apply(ue_vector *vect, int (*f)(void *state, void *data), void *state);
```

I have found this useful - especially for printing the data.

This applies `f()` to each element of the vector.

```
// Pseudo code
int ue_vector_apply(ue_vector *vect, int (*f)(void *state, void *data), void *state) {
   for each data in the vector {
     int result = f(state, vect->data);
     if (result) return result;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Capacity**

I see little value exposing `.capacity` to the user.

Could drop that:

```
// ue_vector*  ue_vector_start         (size_t init_capacity, size_t data_size);
ue_vector*  ue_vector_start         (size_t data_size);

// size_t      ue_vector_capacity      (const ue_vector* const vect);
```

**Documentation**

The .h deserve comments explaining the overall functionality and some function details/limits.

Assume the user does **not** have or may not want access to the *.c file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! You really mean that including only necessary files in .h and others in .c files reduce compilation time?

Comment: @khasanovasad Assume your `ue_vector.h` file is included in _many_ other .c files - it is a generic vector code after all.  Wise to spend the effort to 1) reduce compile time in those `N` other files and 2) those other files may not like your including unnecessary .h files.  As for this `ue_vector.c` file, there are few concerns with a reduced .h file set.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

## Assert is a Debug Tool

The code makes heave use of the assert macro() for logic. The problem with this is that when the code is optimized and not being debugged the code generated for `assert()` statement simply disappears. If you want the error checking to be there in production code than don't use the [assert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) function, use if statements and standard print methods.

> This macro is disabled if, at the moment of including <assert.h>, a macro with the name NDEBUG has already been defined. This allows for a coder to include as many assert calls as needed in a source code while debugging the program and then disable all of them for the production version by simply including a line like:
> #define NDEBUG
> at the beginning of the code, before the inclusion of <assert.h>.

Comment: I only need error checking during Debug mode. The Release code is supposed to be error free. That's is why I chose assertions over ugly & noisy if statements... Correct me if I am wrong, though,

Comment: @khasanovasad Do not assume that malloc() won't fail in production. Do not assume that the user of the library will provide correct inputs to begin with.

Comment: Would it be OK if I used If-Else style of error handling after malloc() and use assertions elsewhere?

Comment: All values that malloc() is based on should be checked before use. One of the main problems with any code is user input and there should be checking on it.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. Thanks a ton )

Comment: I believe there was a way for debug mode, I think that could be used with `#if`. But that of course would only be used for *extra* checks.